# Why is ww35 used in some URLs?

Tags: url, url-rewriting, no-www, web-hosting

A question asked on my website here http://www.wrangle.in/topic/av5b5ymlhoyc/what-is-the-difference-between-www-or-ww

I want to give them answer but I didn't find anywhere on google. So I thought better asking it here.

Answer (score 0):

`www.` Is just a cname setup though the A Records at your DNS registrar or DNS manager though name servers. `ww35.` is most likely a CNAME or Sub Domain, but both the same and depends on how the web hosting is setup. You could even setup `www.` as a sub domain if you wanted.